# Count the longest stretch of consecutive patterns

Tags: awk, bioinformatics, pattern-matching

I have a sequence file:

```
$ cat file
CACCGTTGCCAAACAATG
TTAGAAGCCTGTCAGCCT
CATTGCTCTCAGACCCAC
GATGTACGTCACATTAGA
ACACGGAATCTGCTTTTT
CAGAATTCCCAAAGATGG
```

I want to calculate the longest stretch of C+T. I could only count total C+T, but I want the longest stretch.

```
$ cat file | awk '{ print $0, gsub(/[cCtT]/,"",$1)}'
CACCGTTGCCAAACAATG 9
TTAGAAGCCTGTCAGCCT 10
CATTGCTCTCAGACCCAC 12
GATGTACGTCACATTAGA 8
ACACGGAATCTGCTTTTT 11
CAGAATTCCCAAAGATGG 7
```

The *Expected result* would be to show the longest C+T stretch.

```
CACCGTTGCCAAACAATG 9 2
TTAGAAGCCTGTCAGCCT 10 3
CATTGCTCTCAGACCCAC 12 5
GATGTACGTCACATTAGA 8 2
ACACGGAATCTGCTTTTT 11 6
CAGAATTCCCAAAGATGG 7 5
```

Comment: You don't care about the fact that the longest stretch may occur across a newline?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FWIW here's a way to do it in perl, using `max` from `List::Util`

```
$ perl -MList::Util=max -lpe '$_ .= " " . max 0, map length, /[CT]+/gi' file
CACCGTTGCCAAACAATG 2
TTAGAAGCCTGTCAGCCT 3
CATTGCTCTCAGACCCAC 5
GATGTACGTCACATTAGA 2
ACACGGAATCTGCTTTTT 6
CAGAATTCCCAAAGATGG 5
```

Comment: Reverting this answer to match `/[CT]*/` might be better in a bioinformatics setting, since an oligonucleotide like `AGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAG` with zero matches will then be properly assigned a `0` value in the second column.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ awk '{ split($0, a, "[^CTct]+"); m=0
         for (i in a) {
             len=length(a[i])
             if (len > m) m=len
         }
         print $0, m  }' file
CACCGTTGCCAAACAATG 2
TTAGAAGCCTGTCAGCCT 3
CATTGCTCTCAGACCCAC 5
GATGTACGTCACATTAGA 2
ACACGGAATCTGCTTTTT 6
CAGAATTCCCAAAGATGG 5
```

This `awk` program splits each line on runs of anything that is not  upper or lower case `C` or `T`.  It then loops over the bits that the split results in, finding the longest one.  It then prints the original line together with the found maximum length.

Since Roman looked at timings for various solutions, here's a quicker solution:

```
awk -F "[^CTct]+" '
    m = 0
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) {
        len = length($i)
        if (len > m) m = len
    }
    print m' file | paste file -
```

It's quicker since it only splits the lines once. The first code additionally tries to split the input lines on whitespaces.

Timing it using `mawk` shows 0.79s on 500000 lines.  The first solution uses 1.69s on the same data, showing that it's *probably* the split operation that takes the most time.

Comment: Should be `<= NF`. Is that wall clock time or CPU time? That's significant as the two process variant would be impacted by the number of CPU cores.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Wall clock. Dual processor system. Hyperthreading disabled.

Comment: In the above example, can you please suggest how to print the starting and end point of the longest stretch within the given sequence

Answer (score 3):

Faster GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk -v FPAT='[ctCT]+' \
'{ 
     max_l = t_len = 0;
     for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) {
         len = length($i);
         if (len > max_l) max_l = len;
         t_len += len
     }
     print $0, t_len, max_l
 }' inputfile
```

The output:

```
CACCGTTGCCAAACAATG 9 2
TTAGAAGCCTGTCAGCCT 10 3
CATTGCTCTCAGACCCAC 12 5
GATGTACGTCACATTAGA 8 2
ACACGGAATCTGCTTTTT 11 6
CAGAATTCCCAAAGATGG 7 5
```

---

Time performance comparison (test `inputfile` has about 120000 lines):

```
$ time awk -v FPAT='[ctCT]+' '{ max_l = t_len = 0; for (i=1; i <= NF; i++) { len = length($i); if (len > max_l) max_l = len; t_len += len } print $0, t_len, max_l }' inputfile > /dev/null

real    0m1.018s
user    0m0.948s
sys 0m0.012s

$ time awk '{ split($0, a, "[^CTct]+"); m=0; for (i in a) { len=length(a[i]); if (len > m) m=len } print $0, m }' inputfile > /dev/null

real    0m1.802s
user    0m1.688s
sys 0m0.028s

$ time perl -MList::Util=max -lpe '$_ = "$_ " . max map { length $_ } /[CT]*/gi' inputfile > /dev/null

real    0m1.216s
user    0m1.160s
sys 0m0.016s

$ time sed 'h;y/cCtT/xxxx/;x;H;s/./x/g;G; s/^\(x*\).*\n.*\1.*\n/\1 /; s/^x\{10\}/1/;s/$/:9876543210xxxxxxxxx/; s/^\(1*\)\(x*\) \(.*\):.*\(.\).\{9\}\2$/\3 \1\4/' inputfile > /dev/null

real    1m4.165s
user    1m2.784s
sys 0m0.352s
```

Comment: It would be better to time a single execution on a large dataset rather than multiple executions on a small dataset.  That would give a truer picture of which _code_ is faster rather than how long it would take to start up the programs.

Comment: @Kusalananda, thanks for the suggestion. I've made a test file with 120000 lines and rerun the "benchmark". My approach still remains the fastest one.

Comment: Yes, that look better. I've also modified my solution to split on `[^CTct]+` (note the plus). That should make fewer bits to test against in my code.

Comment: ok, that's better. See the extended "benchmark" results

Comment: I wonder how this compares in speed to a C solution?

Comment: Trying your `awk` code results in two columns added to each line, each column containing the length of the oligonucleotide. For the OP's example data that means two colums of `18` added to each line. The `perl` answers work properly as does @Kusalananda 's first `awk` answer. Maybe something about my `awk` (I'm on MacOS)?

Comment: @jubilatious1 On macOS, you would have to ensure that you use GNU Awk (the native Awk is not GNU on that system). You may install GNU Awk from e.g. Homebrew.

Answer (score 3):

With `sed` (assuming no more than 19 characters per line), just for the fun of it and using the greedy properties of RE matching:

```
sed '
  h;y/cCtT/xxxx/;x;H;s/./x/g;G
  s/^\(x*\).*\n.*\1.*\n/\1 /
  s/^x\{10\}/1/;s/$/:9876543210xxxxxxxxx/
  s/^\(1*\)\(x*\) \(.*\):.*\(.\).\{9\}\2$/\3 \1\4/'
```

A variation on @Kusalananda's solution:

```
awk -F '[^cCtT]+' '
  {
    max = 0
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++)
      if ((l = length($i)) > max)
        max = l
    print $0, max
  }'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try also

```
awk '
        {T0 = $0
         while (match (T0, /[CTct]+/))  {if (RLENGTH > MX) MX = RLENGTH
                                         T0 = substr (T0, RSTART+RLENGTH)
                                        }
         print $0, MX
        }
' file
```

timing is a wee bit faster than the other `awk` proposals.

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```
~$ raku -ne 'print "$_ | "; put max($/.List, :by(*.chars)).chars given m:g/ <+[cCtT]>* /;'   file
```

Above is an answer coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Briefly, the awk-like `-ne` non-autoprinting command line flags are used. A `m:g/ … /` global match is sought, and from that match object (i.e. `$/`) the `max` is computed `:by(*.chars)` by the number of consecutive characters.

Without the trailing `.chars` call the code returns the actual nucleotide match (i.e. string); with the trailing `.chars` call the code returns the max consecutive nucleotide `char`acters (i.e. length). The output first `print`s the topic variable input (i.e. `$_ |` ), then the `max` match:

Sample Input (note line 6 contains no match):

```
CACCGTTGCCAAACAATG
TTAGAAGCCTGTCAGCCT
CATTGCTCTCAGACCCAC
GATGTACGTCACATTAGA
ACACGGAATCTGCTTTTT
AGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAG
CAGAATTCCCAAAGATGG
```

Sample Output:

```
CACCGTTGCCAAACAATG | 2
TTAGAAGCCTGTCAGCCT | 3
CATTGCTCTCAGACCCAC | 5
GATGTACGTCACATTAGA | 2
ACACGGAATCTGCTTTTT | 6
AGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAG | 0
CAGAATTCCCAAAGATGG | 5
```

Of course, this might seem like we're working too hard. Raku has a `.raku` routine (or `.perl` routine) to report on the internal representation of data objects. Thus the `max` found within the  `$/` match-variable can be returned like so (simply change `.chars` to `.raku` from the code at top):

```
~$ raku -ne 'put max($/.List, :by(*.chars)).raku given m:g/ <+[cCtT]>* /;'   file
Match.new(:orig("CACCGTTGCCAAACAATG"), :from(2), :pos(4))
Match.new(:orig("TTAGAAGCCTGTCAGCCT"), :from(7), :pos(10))
Match.new(:orig("CATTGCTCTCAGACCCAC"), :from(5), :pos(10))
Match.new(:orig("GATGTACGTCACATTAGA"), :from(8), :pos(10))
Match.new(:orig("ACACGGAATCTGCTTTTT"), :from(12), :pos(18))
Match.new(:orig("AGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAG"), :from(0), :pos(0))
Match.new(:orig("CAGAATTCCCAAAGATGG"), :from(5), :pos(10))
```

Putting it all together:

```
~$ raku -ne 'print "$_ | "; my $max1 = max($/.List, :by(*.chars)) given m:g/ <+[cCtT]>* /; put $max1.chars ~" | "~ $max1.raku;'   file
CACCGTTGCCAAACAATG | 2 | Match.new(:orig("CACCGTTGCCAAACAATG"), :from(2), :pos(4))
TTAGAAGCCTGTCAGCCT | 3 | Match.new(:orig("TTAGAAGCCTGTCAGCCT"), :from(7), :pos(10))
CATTGCTCTCAGACCCAC | 5 | Match.new(:orig("CATTGCTCTCAGACCCAC"), :from(5), :pos(10))
GATGTACGTCACATTAGA | 2 | Match.new(:orig("GATGTACGTCACATTAGA"), :from(8), :pos(10))
ACACGGAATCTGCTTTTT | 6 | Match.new(:orig("ACACGGAATCTGCTTTTT"), :from(12), :pos(18))
AGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAG | 0 | Match.new(:orig("AGAGAGAGAGAGAGAGAG"), :from(0), :pos(0))
CAGAATTCCCAAAGATGG | 5 | Match.new(:orig("CAGAATTCCCAAAGATGG"), :from(5), :pos(10))
```

For more precise output, the `$max1.raku` call can be replaced by calls to `$max1.orig`, and/or `$max1.from`, and/or `$max1.pos`, etc.

https://docs.raku.org/routine/max
https://docs.raku.org
https://raku.org